# VS2008 rdl vs. VS2010 rdl data display

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have VS2008 where i have a report that produces tablix with one field from one dataset. It displays values correctly. They are Numbers (0,00, 10,00, 15,00, 25,00 - using expression =Fields!TaxRate.Value - from thr correct Dataset).
They display correctly in RDL in VS 2008 (using preview).

When I copy RDL, rename it to RDLC and open it in VS 2010 (Azure emulator), in output it creates the correct number of fields in table - but it doesn't fill them with data, they are empty.

All other fields - 100 or more, from 4 or 5 datasets - display correctly.

Here are the screenshots:

In report:
[image]

In base:
[image]

Can someone show me where I'm making mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify "TaxID" in report.

Comment: The fields are from the same dataset that has the correct values. The TaxID isn't in dataset.